# How to handle KB5025823 X509 changes correctly?

Tags: certificates, saml, microsoft, pkcs12

According this [change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5025823-change-in-how-net-applications-import-x-509-certificates-bf81c936-af2b-446e-9f7a-016f4713b46b) here, .NET Core will handle imports of X509 certificates differently.

Using .NET 6, for the value of `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs12UnspecifiedPasswordIterationLimit`, we either have to specify -1 to ignore this check, or put a value high enough to satisfy all test cases.

We certainly want to keep that check, but the problem is that we do not know what the upper value of required iterations will be. We get a call back from Azure AD with a SAMLRequest and we can only assume, say, 10,000,000 will be enough.

Is there a documented maximum value somewhere ?

Comment: PKCS12 itself does not set a limit. I expect nearly all systems implement niter using `int` in C or C++ which is almost always 32 bits signed, with a maximum slightly over 2 billion. But in practice anything much over about ten million takes so long to create noone will (legitimately) use it. [Mozilla (Firefox) found a Windows limit of 600k](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1436873#c11) and I get the same thing today in W10-22H2.